# Why Angular components require bootstrapping?

Tags: angular

So, I created a simple Angular application with two components (I show just the relevant pieces of the code):

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Block2Component
  ],
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent, Block2Component ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My landing page wants to render 2 top level components:

```
<body style="background-color: rgb(234, 240, 220);">
  <p>Content that came from index.HTML</p>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <app-block2></app-block2>
</body>
```

In this state of the code it builds and renders the page fine. But what is the meaning of a component bootstrapping? I tried removing component name from the bootstrap section of the module, and the component disappeared from the page. Well, bootstrapping is needed for something. But for what?

The root module is bootstrapped from the `main.ts` file. This means that Angular knows the list of available components. Why can't it do the bootstrapping under the hood once it sees the selector of a component on the landing page template?

Comment: Because that was how the people who designed angular wanted it to work <shrug>. It's essentially [dependency injection](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)

Answer (score -1):

**Bootstrap Array**

The application launches by bootstrapping the root AppModule, which is also referred to as an entryComponent. Among other things, the bootstrapping process creates the component(s) listed in the bootstrap array and inserts each one into the browser DOM.

Each bootstrapped component is the base of its own tree of components. Inserting a bootstrapped component usually triggers a cascade of component creations that fill out that tree.

While you can put more than one component tree on a host web page, most applications have only one component tree and bootstrap a single root component.

This one root component is usually called AppComponent and is in the root module's bootstrap array.

Comment: This is not an answer. This is direct copy of documentation.